# Is it possible request angular server in nodejs server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, xmlhttprequest, node.js-domains

I have two servers running now, one is NodeJS, the other is Angular.
NodeJS listens port 3000, angular listens port 8000. Is it possible to get angular website and then update at port 3000?
For example, users can open localhost:8000 to access my angular application. Is it possible for users to access angular application through localhost:3000 which is my NodeJS service.
Currently, I did something like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    request('localhost:8000', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        res.send(body);
      }
   })
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Nodejs service has been invoked');
});
```

When I access localhost:3000, I couldn't see anything, the reason is couldn't find localhost:3000/assets/css/main.css, localhost:3000/filename. Because these files can only be found at localhost:8000.

I couldn't figure out. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tweak LoopBack's middleware configuration, **server/middleware.json**, to look like this:

```
{
"initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {}
},
"initial": {
    "compression": {}
},
"session": {},
"auth": {},
"parse": {},
"routes": {
    "loopback#status": {
        "paths": "/status"
    }
},
"files": {
    "loopback#static": {
        "params": "$!../client"
    }
},
"final": {
    "loopback#urlNotFound": {}
},
"final:after": {
    "errorhandler": {}
}
}
```

The **files** key above is the most important part. This setting tells the LoopBack server to serve static files from the client directory. Once you've tweaked this configuration, you can create an index.html file that displays your content.